# RxJava2. Flowable to behave same way as Observable does?

Tags: java, rx-java2

It seems like mental overhead to use both `Observable` and `Flowable` in the same project for `RXJava` 2.

Say to distinguish in the interfaces that this method return Observable so there is not back-pressure this one does so it is with back-pressure support.

But in the end of the day we can just use `Flowable` to make things simpler?

Then:

Can I make `Flowable` to be faster to turn off pressure to behave same way as `Observable` does?

Comment: Have you read the [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#which-type-to-use) about which type to use for what? Otherwise, you can't turn off the backpressure on `Flowable`, at most you can unbound certain stages but that may not last long as either further operators bound the request amounts again or you get `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to myself: use Flowable everywhere. For all API that exposed themselves through the Net.

**My use case:** I use RX Java to defining RX API to the Web and itneracting with other microservices by Net.

From my understanding, the projectreactor https://projectreactor.io/ (another rx iml) project there is even no question whether to go with backpressure or not. It is there for all Flux

Going back to RxJava2. It seems to me that in the RX Java it was decided to keep Observable for the backward compatibility purposes primary. (there is no good explanation why not)

And when it comes to HTTP I found that I need it even for smaller sets. Usually. Event if I return **less than 1000 items** to the client it does not mean that it can handle it at once (it can be busy doing other stuff), so I would go with backpressure.

So I do not won't to overcomplicate things / api / code, will go with Flowable everywhere until I see any of Observable.

Comment: how is that an answer?

Comment: updated. but as I said. Since nobody answered other then referring to the doc. I just want to close this question to myself.

Comment: I understand, but on SO we are creating QA useful to the public, not just for 1 person. Thanks for updating

Comment: yeah. made it even more clear. updated all about my use case. Unaccepted my answer, there is room for others.